# How to get access to variables from other class

Tags: java, class, variables, import

So I would like to use the variable "kierunek" from this class

```
public class Snake extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
char kierunek = 'D';
```

to this class

```
import pl.java.Snake.*;

public class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
```

importing shows "Unused import statement", I tried to find soulution, but there is nothing helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java you will have to either have to create a public Getter Method, or make the variable itself public.

As a object oriented Language Java differentiates between different access modifiers. More on that here: [What is the difference between public, protected, package-private and private in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in)

Usually one should use Getter and Setter as accessors for the variables in order to avoid creating Problems.

More on why here: [Why use getters and setters/accessors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors)

Answer (score 0):

**"Unused import statement"** Means that you haven't used your imported class yet.

It triggers for any class, like for example, good old `scanner`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

You will get the same warning until you use said class it. In this case, by creating a Scanner object:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Also, do you have both of your classes inside the same package? If so, you don't have to import it, you can just call it.

(Like Daniel said, I recommend using setters and getters when interacting with your class attributes so you can keep them private)